# Confusion about use of "to" after "told" in passive voice

Tags: passive-voice

The active voice is
Will she tell us the truth ?

The passive voice has two options

Will the truth be told to us by her ?

Or

Will the truth be told us by her ?

I.e. will "to" follow us in passive voice.
It feels right to include to in passive voice.

Is this also correct?

Will the truth be told by her?  Can we ommit "us" assuming that this is directed to people referred as "us"

Comment: The indirect object of the verb is not directly relevant to the passive form, which involves the shifting of the direct object into the subject position. However, if you're trying to recast the sentence as a passive, without dropping  pieces of the sentence, you would include the indirect object (or the prepositional phrase, as the case may be).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options in the passive:

1. Will the truth be told **to us** by her?
2. Will **we** be told the truth by her?

The first is the passive of **"Will she tell the truth to us?"** whilst the second one is the passive of **"Will she tell us the truth?"**

Both the passive and the active forms are valid and correct.